# Using HTML code in Swing

Tags: java, html, swing, joptionpane

I can't figure out how to use variables in HTML, string is a variable in this case.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>Error #1<br> + string +</html>","Error",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

this output: Error #1 + string

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>Error #1<br></html>" + string ,"Error",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

this output: Error #1

is there a way to use string variables in HTML?

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>Error #1<br>" + string  + "</html>","Error",

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like

```
"<html>Error #1<br>" + string + "</html>"
```

?
If you want to concatenate the `string` variable to the html you have there, it must be outside the quotes, otherwise it will be treated as a literal, as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null,
    "<html>Error #1<br>" + string + "</html>",
    "Error",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Though note that logically `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE` should be `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:    `"<html>Error #1<br>" + string + "</html>"`

A string  literal  in java consists  of  zero  or  more  characters  enclosed  in  ***double  quotes***. So anything satisfies this condition will also be regarded as string too. You will need to close the String before appending the `string`.

So if the `string = "Hi to stack"`:

Then `"<html>Error #1<br>" + string + "</html>"` will result in:

```
"<html>Error #1<br>Hi to stack</html>"
```